# Windows 7 - Video thumbnails not showing previews

Tags: windows-7

The icon thumbnails of videos stopped showing a preview of the video itself, they only show an icon indicating it's a video. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.

1. Click menu: `Organize` - **`Folder and search options`**. You see the Folder Options dialog box showing up.
2. Click **`View`** tab and uncheck `Always show icons, never thumbnails`.
3. Click **OK** to apply the change.

You can also Use  Disk Cleanup to delete thumbnail cache(Open run dialog, type `cleanmgr` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can optimize the folder to "video".
just click on the folder properties -> Customize and check if the right selection is set.

Another idea would be to check whether your IconCache.db is full or not.
C:\Users\USER\APPDATA\local. you can rename it and resart. After that it will be rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Icaros thumbnail previewer instead of using sh$&tty windows thumbn. previewer

http://www.videohelp.com/download/Icaros_v2.2.3.exe

> Icaros can provide Windows Explorer thumbnails, for essentially any
>   video media format supported by FFmpeg, this includes popular
>   filetypes such as: Mkv, Flv, Avi, Mp4, Mov, Rmvb, M2ts, Ogm etc.
>   Besides the FFmpeg supported filetypes, Icaros also contains custom
>   parsers, which can produce Cover Art thumbnails for Mkv, Flac, Ape,
>   and Mpc files. Icaros also provides Windows Explorer properties for
>   the following popular filetypes: Mkv, Flv, Ogm, Ogv, Ogg, Flac, Ape,
>   and Mpc. Requires .NET 4.0.